Get 500 error when fetching the data from controller
So I tried to fetch the controller.
 useEffect(() => { displayEstates() }, []);

 async function displayEstates() {
     const response = await fetch('/api/estatedto', {
             headers: new Headers({
                 'estateType': 'flat'
             })
         });
         const data = await response.json();
         setEstates(data);
 }

I get a 500 error, but when I reload the page, the data fetches okay. Also, when I use a timeout, the page loads fine when I run the app. But the data loads really long.
async function displayEstates() {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/api/estatedto', {
            headers: new Headers({
                'estateType': 'flat'
            })
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        setEstates(data);
    }, 1000);
}

The interesting thing is that when I set a breakpoint in either the React app or the .NET app, I don't get such an error. I think maybe the error occurs because of timing when the data can't be retrieved in time.
